# Same hop count for different destinations in traceroute

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

When I use `traceroute` (actually `tracert` command for Windows) for different destination addresses, I always get same hop counts.

For example:
For `superuser.com`, I get:

```
Tracing route to superuser.com [151.101.1.69]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     6 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     2 ms     3 ms     3 ms  10.201.0.1
  3     4 ms     2 ms     2 ms  angeldropsltd.com [103.242.217.37]
  4     8 ms     4 ms     4 ms  151.101.1.69

Trace complete.
```

For `microsoft.com`, I get:

```
Tracing route to microsoft.com [23.100.122.175]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     3 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     5 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.201.0.1
  3     4 ms     2 ms     2 ms  angeldropsltd.com [103.242.217.37]
  4     7 ms     4 ms     4 ms  23.100.122.175

Trace complete.
```

It is similar for all other sites I have tried so far.

I want to know the possible reasons why this is happening. I have some brief knowledge how `traceroute` works. Different destinations should have different hop counts. My ISP (*AngelDrops*) might not have all the destination servers **directly** connected. I think, my ISP is doing something here. So what are the reasons for this happening?

Comment: Try with `tcptraceroute`, as bare traceroute is using UDP/ICMP that is often specifically filtered/handled differently from "true" user traffic, often over TCP, like the probable HTTP examples you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to give you my best shot at explaining this. But, I don't know why your ISP is doing it.

First, it's important to understand how Traceroute works. Traceroute works by settings the TTL (Time To Live) value in the IP packets that it sends out. Each hop your packet takes along the way will decrement the TTL by 1. When TTL reaches 0, if your packet has not reached it's intended destination then a ICMP Unreachable message is sent back containing the IP address of the last router reached.

So, when you issue the `tracert` command, Windows sends out a series of ICMP packets with incrementing TTL values. The first packet goes out with TTL 1, the next packet with TTL 2, and so on. In this manner, each router along the path to your destination can be discovered - if it replies with ICMP unreachable. If it just drops the packet, you get the * * * response from tracert and no information.

So, what appears to be happening here is that your ISP (AngelDrops) is not honoring the TTL setting. Instead, it appears they are stripping or filtering that information from the packet when it reaches them. Because of that, once the packet reaches AngelDrops they are forwarding it along to it's destination with a much higher "default" TTL. This causes the packet to traverse all the way to it's destination and the final response you see is from the destination.

TTL in an IP packet is really designed to prevent network loops where a packet continues to bounce around inside the network in a circle forever.

I hope that makes sense. Now, why does your ISP do that? I'm not particularly sure, but it could be that they see tampering with the TTL as a possible security risk to their network and thus they filter it. Honoring your TTL data is not really necessary for the proper operation of the network.

Being that I don't know anything about [AngelDrops](http://www.angeldropsltd.com/web/), it could be there is something non-standard about this ISP, maybe it is wireless, or a VPN service, or something like that. There are a number of possible technicalities why things get weird with them.

Based on what I see in your traceroute it appears you are on some kind of shared internet service. You aren't getting a real public IP, so you are probably behind some kind of NATted network where you are sharing the same public IP with multiple users. This would explain everything.

Comment: Very well explained! I want to share a little more. My home router (192.168.0.1) is not directly connected to AngelDrops ISP. Actually my home router is connected to a local shop near my home for internet service. They are connected to the ISP, and they are sharing it with several houses (including my house). They sometimes change ISP whatever they want. So the ISP I am using today, may not be the same tomorrow, even though my home router will be connected to the same local shop tomorrow. Actually I have found this weird `tracert` thing just after they had changed the ISP to AngelDrops.